# Constrain Keras regression output

Tags: keras, distribution, keras-layer

I successfully trained an NN using Keras. However, predictions for a few samples are wildly off. Now, I would like to constrain predictions to a certain interval (say 5 to 10) which is the only interval in which predictions may ever lie for my particular problem. More generally, I would like to force outputs to be of a specific distribution (e.g. standard normal).
I tried Keras lambda layers 
keras.layers.Lambda(function, output_shape=None, mask=None, arguments=None)
with Keras probability distributions as the function 
(https://www.tensorflow.org/probability).
However, it does not work this way. Is there any way to constrain predictions in Keras regression to a certain interval and/or distribution?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason why its a good practice to normalize the labels of your data, say to the `[0, 1]` or `[-1, 1]` range. Then its easy to constrain the neural network output to one of these ranges, by putting the `sigmoid` or `tanh` activation function at the output layer.

This is what is generally done for convolutional object detectors, and it should work fine for your problem. There is no way for neural networks to output probability distributions, unless your model outputs the parameters of the probability distribution, but just normalizing works fine and its easier.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds good. However, with tanh or sigmoid, values on the edges of the interval (close to 0 or 1 in your example) might become very unlikely, right? However,  values on the edges might be equally likely in my case.

Comment: @Tim No, edge values aren't unlikely

Answer (score 0):

Scale your training and test data using MinMaxScaler() before the training and use the scaled data to train the model. Then, your model predictions will be inside the defined scale and you apply the inverse transformation.

before scale your data:

```html
minmax_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
minmax_scaler.fit([[-130],[-20]]) # this is a custom scale with min=-130, max=-20. 


#scale your y_train, y_test
y_train_minmax = minmax_scaler.transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_test_minmax = minmax_scaler.transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))

#Train your model with the scaled labels...
history = model.fit(X_train_std, y_train_minmax, epochs=batch_size, validation_split=0.85, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])

#Make predictions and inverse transform your data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_std)

y_pred_values = minmax_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```